# Webview loadurl Opening the default browser

Tags: android, webview

I have created one activity along with webview and loaded some url in it.But when i loaded google url in webview it opening in device default browser but when i loaded some other urls in it,it works fine for me.

Permission added in manifest -

For ex -

This is open in device browser

```
WebSettings webSettings = webVw.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webVw.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

This is opens in webview -

```
webVw = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webVw); WebSettings webSettings = webVw.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webVw.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com");
```

**Q:** Why this happens?
Is there any other workaround to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webView.loadUrl("url");
```

Check the WebView tutorial [from here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html). Just implement the web client and set it before loadUrl. The simplest way is:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: whats the issue you are getting

Comment: Just implement the web client and set it before loadUrl. The simplest way is:   myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Comment: @sanil I have edited my answer please go through that and let me know , is  it solve your issue or not

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this in front of your url like this

```
webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=" + yourUrl);
```